# How to check if an object of type Any is an enum and convert it to an Int?

Tags: swift

I'm checking if an object of type Any is an enum by 
`Mirror(reflecting: $0.value).displayStyle == Mirror.DisplayStyle.enum`,
but there's no way for me to convert this Any Object to an Enum except by casting it to AnyHashable or an Int. Is there any other approach to doing this that would be safer?

Edit: I would like to be able to do this generically with any enum type. Not just one specific enum.

Comment: Can you show me some example codes of what you tried and what didn't work?